# SQL error The conversion of the nvarchar value '4678444992' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone help me solve this issue with INT

```
Select 
    Location, Population, 
    MAX(total_cases) AS HighestInfectionCount,  
    MAX((total_cases / population)) * 100 AS PercentPopulationInfected
From 
    .CovidDeaths
--Where location like '%states%'
Group By 
    Location, Population
Order By 
    PercentPopulationInfected desc
```

I get this error

> The conversion of the nvarchar value '4678444992' overflowed an int column

Comment: tag with database platform.  That's bigger than a 32-bit number can hold.  Show table DLL and sample data.  depending on the db, you may be able to cast to a higher precision data type, but can't say w/o the details

Comment: Nowhere has a population that high though (unless it includes whole continents possibly?). If you do need numbers that high you're gonna need a bigger datatype

Comment: You should change the datatype of column Population from nvarchar to bigint. You will still have integer division  to deal with  but that will solve the first issue. Pretty sure that number is for whole of Asia

Comment: my respect to @OldProgrammer - short and to the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum integer value in SQL Server that can be placed in in a column type of `integer` is 2,147,483,647. So you have exceed it value more than twice.

The SQL is ok by itself and its result can be calculated an displayed by the server with no problems, but you, obviously, are trying to insert this result into another table that has an `int` column.

So a value can't be inserted due to exceeding and you've get this error. In this case you can create the new column type of `Bigint` in the target table, copy all the data from the old `int` column, rename old column, then rename a new column with an original name of the last column. Phew)) now, if everything is fine you can drop the old column

**UPD**

My previous answer is about a case, when all the data is numeric, nevertheless it can be useful, because this weird calculation doesn't guarantee, that the result wouldn't be inserted into the some target table with int column.

Speaking of a solution - you must cast big pseudo number within the request

```
Select 
    Location, Population, 
    MAX(total_cases) as HighestInfectionCount,  
    MAX((cast(total_cases as bigint)/population)) * 100 as PercentPopulationInfected
From 
    .CovidDeaths
--Where location like '%states%'
Group By
    Location, Population
Order By 
    PercentPopulationInfected desc
```

IMHO implicit conversions is the worst things ever

Comment: "obviously, are trying to insert this result into another table that has an int column" - the query they show has no sign of that. Probably the cast is implicit as `total_cases` is `int` due to `total_cases/population`

Comment: yep, my bad. it's about conversion